# How to insert data on to the server in Android Application

Tags: php, android, sql

I am developing an android application where the user data should be pushed onto the server .How can i do that ? I was able to get data from the server but unable to insert it. Code snippet would be good.I have tried this but it doesn't work.

Java Code :

```
String data="xyz.org/json.php"+"?"+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8") + "="+"order";
URL url;
url = new URL(data);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

In json.php :

```
$data = urldecode($_GET['data']);
if($data=="order")
{
   $query="insert into xyz values('$x','$y','$z')";
   $query_run=mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: Before you do something like this - read about SQL Injection!! Your code is a definite candidate!!! Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a httppost or httpget dependance on the your url method for that you can use Httppost and get follow this [url](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89) you get some idea  and also check this [url](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) for asynctask beacuse you have to put all the network related you have to put in the asynctask.